# Server Error 500: No value present. Spring Boot deployment on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy the second web-app I've built with Pivotal's Cloud Foundry platform. I've got the app up and running, but when I submit the form to create a new Event, I'm getting a server error 500 that says No value present. Everything works how it should when I test the application locally, I'm only getting the error on the actual, deployed app. So I have two questions: Does anyone have any suggestions of why I'd get a server error on Cloud Foundry and not locally? And how can I debug the back-end of my app on the CF server (I've only been learning to code for about a year and have very little experience with deployment). Is there a way to get Java's System.out.println to print to the browser's console like I can in JavaScript? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you check the logs of your app to see if there are any stack traces being printed. You can tail the logs of your app using the following command line command:

```
cf logs [APP_NAME]
```

Once you start tailing the logs, try submitting your form again to see if any errors are printed to your console.

Comment: By default, Spring Boot should log to STDOUT/STDERR, so everything should show up under `cf logs`, and if a 500 error occurs you should definitely see a stack trace there as well. Just make sure that you're not setting `logging.file` or `logging.path` in application.properties as that will log to the file system, and you won't see output in `cf logs`.